# Definition of "degree of interaction" in the MARS model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression, splines

What exactly is the meaning of the "degree of interaction" or "interaction degree" in the MARS model?

e.g.  R: `earth(..., degree=2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The degree of interaction is the maximum degree of input terms in the regression function. For example a model such as $y=0.5x_1+0.2x_2 -.3$ has degree $1$. While $y=0.5x_1+0.2x_2 + .05x_1x_2-.3$ has degree $2$. For simplicity, I have given a linear regression example instead of [MARS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines).

Or, paraphrasing from the [wikipedia entry](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines), something like
$\text{ozone} =  5.2 
      +    0.93 \max(0, \mathrm{temp} - 58)  
      -   0.64 \max(0, \mathrm{temp} - 68)$
$     -   0.016 \max(0, \mathrm{wind} - 7) \max(0, 200 - \text{vis})$

is an example of a MARS model with degree of interaction $2$.